# How to change audio tempo and pitch individuality using ffmpeg?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, ffmpeg, audiotrack

I have managed to play audio files using ffmpeg and AudioTrack class in my android project. I can change the speed of audio using AudioTrack class setRate method. But it also change the pitch of audio, I want to change only Tempo of audio but I found no solution on net.

anyone can please help me on this as there is no support for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution :**
I tried SoundTouch library. I compiled it successfully for android but then I failed to use its function because I don't know how to use this library to load audio.

But after that I tried library called [Sonic](http://dev.vinux-project.org/sonic/). Its basically for Speech as it use PSOLA algo to change pitch and tempo. But its ok.

Comment: Hi vipul . I am trying to concatenate and change tempo of mp3 files in my android app. As i am new to android I dont know how to use library Sonic that you suggested above. As the work you have done with audio files , I hope that you have solution for my problem. If you can help me out in changing tempo , that will be a great help.

And if you have answer I can post a question for it.  Thank you Vipul

Comment: Hello @Harsh User OpenSL ES library which is a part of android OS and  try this question  [OPEN SL ES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094377/android-how-to-change-playback-rate-of-music-using-opensl-es) This will help you to use OpensSL ES lib.

Comment: @Vipul Purhit I am developing a video player which records a video and manipulates its sound i.e change its pitch. how can i use libsonic for that since it is only working for audio files.

Comment: Hi @VipulPurohit I had gone through the Sonic Library and I saw a talking.bin file in that, so can you tell me how can I make that .bin file by recording or manually from any mp3,etc file.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [atempo filter](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atempo) in ffmpeg 1.0 and later:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f:a atempo=1.25 output.wav
```

`atempo` only accepts values between 0.5 and 2.0, but you can bypass the limitation by chaining multiple filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wav -f:a atempo=2,atempo=1.5 output.wav
```

Comment: But using this shortens the original duration of audio. What if I want to keep the original duration along with the modified pitch?

Comment: On windows with version N-77870 at least it appears you need to spell out the word filter as in `ffmpeg -i input.wav -filter:a atempo=1.25 output.wav`

Comment: Or `ffmpeg -i input.wav -af atempo=1.25 output.wav`

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.wav -af atempo=1.0827 output.wav

Answer (score 2):

Pitch and tempo are very strongly linked. What you're trying to do is called "time stretching", and is a somewhat complicated algorithm. You can find information online about it, and a java library for it can be found [here](http://tarsos.0110.be/artikels/lees/Audio_Time_Stretching_-_Implementation_in_Pure_Java_Using_WSOLA), along with a paper describing the process.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Lri does not work for me, it shows error:

```
'atempo=1.2' is not a suitable output format
```

The next command works properly:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mkv
```

Taken from [ffmpeg.org](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video#Speedingupslowingdownaudio).