# Modify MP3 pitch or tempo

Tags: android

I'm looking for a way to modify tempo or pitch of a MP3 file. Obviously i'm trying first with android clases (SoundPool, MediaPLayer, etc...) but we haven't find anything. I have tested Navigation Audio sample from NDK (using OpenSSL), but not goes in my phone. It runs but donesn't implement any effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351003/audio-pitch-and-tempo-modification)!
and [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260043/how-to-change-audio-tempo-and-pitch-individuality-using-ffmpeg)...