# Audio Pitch and Tempo modification

Tags: android, audio, tempo, pitch-shifting

I need to modify pitch or tempo of an audio, but need to do them separately. Is there any example in Android for that or any library which provides support for Android.

I want to avoid using NDK/JNI for this, since I am not that good into it.

I have already seen Many libraries, although they have a nice tutorial, but I am unable to import them to Eclipse Android project. Help is appreciated :-)

Comment: I suggest soundtouch library is the best choice for your requirement but it is a C library.

Comment: Yeah and I can't make it work in Android, unless there's some tutorial on how to do it :-(

Comment: check this link an example of soundtouch https://github.com/nonameentername/soundtouch-android

Comment: @noob were you able to implement this? I am looking for something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  could try [Tarsos](https://github.com/ederwander/TarsosDSP) !

Here some cool demo links from Tarsos:

http://0110.be/posts/Phase_Vocoding%3A_Time_Stretching_and_Pitch_Shifting_with_TarsosDSP_Java

http://0110.be/posts/Pitch_Shifting_-_Implementation_in_Pure_Java_with_Resampling_and_Time_Stretching

Comment: Thanks @enderwander. I'll have a look on them :-)