# Android - Audio: change pitch and speed independently

Tags: android, audio, pitch-shifting

I have been looking here on SO and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20364320/6427630) answer, which is from Dec 4th 2013, I couldn't find any more recent question/answer about this topic, so here it is...

I have implemented a MediaPlayer in my app and set it to play a song that the user imports from his library.

**I need to implement two sliders that independently allow the user to change the tempo and pitch of the imported audio.**

I have looked through the documentation for some MediaPlayer methods, but I couldn't find anything useful except for `setPlaybackParams()` that unfortunately changes both, tempo and pitch at the same time.

If it's possible I would avoid the NDK since I have no experience at all using it.

Comment: did you find any solutions for it? Working on the same.

Comment: Yes, I ended up using the SoundTouch Library, you need NDK for that though. I works great

Comment: i tried using that, but i am facing a problem there to call some methods from the NDK, have you encountered with the same issue?

Comment: yes, it's not straight forward but not knowing what you did I can't tell what is wrong. You may write a question and leave a link here and I'll check it out