# how to fastforward the song when i press and hold the button

Tags: android, android-music-player

When i play song in music player when i press a button i am forwarding the song for certain time,i am implementing this way,but i need when i press and hold the fast forward button  wan to move the song means acting as our real music player,how can i am implementing please help me how i implement the fast forward button functionality is same as our music player fast forward button.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
            SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

        private ImageButton btnDecreaseSound, btnIncSound, btnReverse, btnPlay, btnForward,
                btnPause;
        private TextView currenttime, endtime;

        private LinearLayout btnRedo, btnDelete;
        private SeekBar songProgressBar;
        private MediaPlayer mp;
        private SongsManager songManager;
        private Utilities utils;
        private int seekForwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
        private int seekBackwardTime = 5000; // 5000 milliseconds
        private int currentSongIndex = 0;
        private SeekBar volumeSeekbar ;
        private AudioManager audioManager ;
        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            // Mediaplayer
            mp = new MediaPlayer();
            songManager = new SongsManager();
            utils = new Utilities();
             final SoundPool spool = null;
                final int soundID = 0;



             audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().AUDIO_SERVICE);
            volumeSeekbar.setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeSeekbar.setProgress(audioManager
                    .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)); 



            // Listeners
            songProgressBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); // Important
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(this); // Important

            // Getting all songs list
            songsList = songManager.getPlayList();

            // By default play first song

            btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.pause();
                            // Changing button image to play button
                            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbtn);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (mp != null) {
                            mp.start();
                            //
                            btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pauseiconbtn);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });




            volumeSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) 
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int progress, boolean arg2) 
                {
                    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            progress, 0);
                }
            });


            btnReverse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // get current song position
                    int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                    if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
                        // forward song
                        mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                    } else {
                        // backward to starting position
                        mp.seekTo(0);
                    }

                }
            });

            btnForward.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()) {
                        // forward song
                        mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                    } else {
                        // forward to end position
                        mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                    }
                }
            });

        public void playSong(int songIndex) {
            // Play song
            try {
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDataSource(songsList.get(songIndex).get("songPath"));
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
                // Displaying Song title
                String songTitle = songsList.get(songIndex).get("songTitle");

                songProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                songProgressBar.setMax(100);

                // Updating progress bar
                updateProgressBar();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void updateProgressBar() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }

        private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
                long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

                // Displaying Total Duration time
                // endtime.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
                // Displaying time completed playing
                currenttime
                        .setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

                //

                String l = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration);
                String l2 = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration);

                long number = totalDuration - currentDuration;

                String timechange = utils.milliSecondsToTimer(number);

                System.out.println("l value: " + timechange);
                endtime.setText("-" + timechange);
                // Updating progress bar
                int progress = (int) (utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration,
                        totalDuration));
                // Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
                songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

                // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
                mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromTouch) {

        }

        /**
         * When user starts moving the progress handler
         * */
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
        }

        /**
         * When user stops moving the progress hanlder
         * */
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
            int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(),
                    totalDuration);

            // forward or backward to certain seconds
            mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

            // update timer progress again
            updateProgressBar();
        }

        /**
         * On Song Playing completed if repeat is ON play same song again if shuffle
         * is ON play random song
         * */
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

            // check for repeat is ON or OFF

            playSong(0);
            currentSongIndex = 0;

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            mp.release();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not override Home button for your custom application. that is reserved. Please google it regarding overriding home button

Please go to this link\, you can get your answer here.
[Android Overriding home key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039500/android-overriding-home-key)

Comment: thanks for your reply,how can i implent the my requirment,can you send me the any code.

Comment: you have to make a custom button to implement this functionality. as you can not override home button.

Comment: can you send me the any sample code for this requirment please

Comment: I have not done it yet, but you can refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260043/how-to-change-audio-tempo-and-pitch-individuality-using-ffmpeg                           and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094377/android-how-to-change-playback-rate-of-music-using-opensl-es?lq=1

Comment: Increasing or decreasing speed of Music is called as Time Streching of audio. You can search many things available on internet with this keyword.