# Record Sound and modulate into different Effects

Tags: android, audio, record

I am working on android app in which i want to do similar work as [Voicechanger App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.baviux.voicechanger)  which is available on playstore.

I know how to record sound from mic but i don't have any idea of how to change the recorded sound to the different effects like Robot, Mega phone etc . 
Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have found some link to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260043/how-to-change-audio-tempo-and-pitch-individuality-using-ffmpeg

Comment: anyone any help .i need this please help me in finding the solution.

Comment: This question is overly broad.  Each individual effect is an entire algorithm unto itself. For an example, google "digital distortion c++" and you'll find hours and hours of reading materials. Also have a look at musicdsp.org and there are a many books on the subject.

Comment: @jaket kindly help me or tell me how i can achieve similar app mentioned above

Comment: sorry but your question is too broad and I have my own job to do. I gave you a few places to begin research.

Comment: @jaket can u have a look at the link and tell me how i can narrow it down.

Comment: Again your question is so broad. This site is for asking very specific programming questions that have a single answer. When you break your question apart there are tons of individual questions. How to record from the mic? how to play to the speaker? Both of these are already answered on this site - many times over. How do you change the recorded sound? The answer depends on the effect and you are asking about dozens of them so there are dozens of different answers. See musicdsp.org for an idea or buy a book. Also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: There are many steps. (1) you need to access the individual PCM data points from the encoded audio data. If you haven't done this and are unfamiliar with other aspects of digital signal processing, this could be a multi-month/year project. I'm not familiar with the specific effects you are naming, but they sound like they involve filtering or granular synthesis, both of which are more difficult than effects like echo, flanging, phasing. Has Android even implemented high-speed/low latency audio yet? If not, doing these in real time is dubious, if that is the goal. Sorry to discourage.