# Change gender of voice via command line/pipe or API

Tags: linux, audio, voice, sox

I'm looking to change the gender of a voice, man to woman and vice versa, preferably on linux. I can change the pitch, but it mostly makes the audio just sound chipmunky.

What are the other things that make a voice gender specific? How can I change them?

I have tried soundtouch, sox and LADSPA/Autotalent. Like I said, the main problem is the high pitch for a man->woman just sounds chipmunky. Anyone have success with this before?

I'm looking to add this into Freeswitch, so a C API is preferable, but I can fallback to a pipe.

Comment: Lol this question is going to hell.

Comment: Yeah I have a bad habit of starting off questions broad and then fine tuning them.

Comment: No I mean it's totally off-topic and people are going to burn it. You have 14k reputation so I'm sure you're already aware of this.

Comment: Off topic of what? This is SO, not some other site from stack exchange.

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260043/how-to-change-audio-tempo-and-pitch-individuality-using-ffmpeg

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Your question has nothing to do with programming and neither does that other question lol. How about the audio engineering site, http://sound.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but I think it's a lack of domain knowledge on your part or a lack of description on my part. ```LADSPA is an acronym for Linux Audio Developer's Simple Plugin API. It is an application programming interface (API) standard for handling audio filters and audio signal processing effects, licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL).```

Comment: But thank you for pointing out sound.stackexchange.

Comment: Another indication would've been you had to create the `ladspa` tag when you asked this question. Yw re: sound.stackexchange

Comment: Possibly also ]dsp.stackexhange.com] would be a good place to ask.

Comment: This is a good question! Do you have an input example, and could you put the chipmunky-maker command line?

Answer (score 0):

(just a first step) -- I would expect that

```
 play  man-voice.wav  pitch 400
```

whould sound like a woman voice

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not going to give command line answer for this Question, but I found that Audacity does the trick. I mean, if Audacity use VST as its plugin base, .. we will be in luck! I am going to update my finding here

https://audacity.wonderhowto.com/how-to/change-pitch-formant-your-voice-with-audacity-335544/

Okay, it uses VST, https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/VST_Plug-ins#VST_support_in_Audacity

Looking to find that specific plugin to change the pitch/gender voice

Answer (score 0):

you can use praat program with its command, you can also use praatio python library to access functionality of praat with its commands