# OpenSL ES change pitch

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, pitch, opensl

I need some help with OpenSL ES - I want to change pitch of mp3 song. The code I used is here: [Android : How to change Playback Rate of music using OpenSL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094377/android-how-to-change-playback-rate-of-music-using-opensl-es) But it is commented in this example. If I uncomment it - it won't work. After executint the code

```
result = (*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_PITCH,
            &uriPlaybackPitch);
    assert(SL_RESULT_SUCCESS == result);
```

uriPlaybackPitch == NULL

LogCat is:

```
OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): create engine
OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): realize the engine
OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): get the engine interface
OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): create output mix
libOpenSLES(7173): class OutputMix interface 0 requested but unavailable MPH=33
OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): realize the output mix
libOpenSLES(7173): Leaving Object::GetInterface (SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED)
libOpenSLES(7173): Leaving PlaybackRate::SetPropertyConstraints (SL_RESULT_FEATURE_UNSUPPORTED)
/OSLESMediaPlayer(7173): Feature Unsupported
libc(7173): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really late here, maybe you've solved it, but that interface is not supported.  OpenSL ES for Android is not a full implementation.  You can find supported interfaces here: http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/ndk/docs/opensles/

Comment: Link seems to be offline

Answer (score 0):

The [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/opensl/opensl-for-android) doc outlines what interfaces are supported on Android.