# Android Sound: seekTo and setPlaybackRate

Tags: android, audio

I am looking for a possibility to play audio on an Android device, that lets me both use the seekTo function(stepping in at a specified part of the audio file) and setPlaybackRate(speeding up/down the playback rate). However, taking a look at the media classes Android provides I could only find the following.

[SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html): Lacks `seekTo`

[AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html): Lacks `seekTo`

[MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html): Lacks `setRate`

Is there a way to play audio in Android without having to write too much code on my own that supplies both these functionalities?

Comment: Any luck with this Adrian? I've got the exact same question!

Comment: @Tiago As far as I recall I never found a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that OpenSL has what you need, but I haven't used it personally. Maybe this here [Android : How to change Playback Rate of music using OpenSL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094377/android-how-to-change-playback-rate-of-music-using-opensl-es) will help you.